# Looking for ways to improve the speed of my python script that uses the Pandas library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization, powerbi

I am fairly new to Pandas, and have started using the library to work with data sets in Power BI.  I recently had to write a snippet of code to run some calculations on a column of integers, but had a hard time translating my code from standard python to Pandas.  The code is essentially casting the column to a list, and then running a loop on the items in the list, appending the resulting number to a new list that I then make into it's own column.

I have read that running loops in Pandas can be slow, and the execution of the code below does indeed seem slow.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Here is the code that I am trying to optimize:

```
import pandas as pd

df = dataset #Required step in Power BI

gb_list = df['Estimated_Size'].T.tolist()
hours_list = []
for size in gb_list:
    hours = -0.50
    try:
        for count in range(0,round(size)):
            if count % 100 == 0:
                hours += .50
            else:
                continue
    except:
        hours = 0
    hours_list.append(hours)

df['Total Hours'] = hours_list
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input data set and expected outputs.

Comment: @ScottBoston Sure thing.  Here is an example of values that could be passed, and what I would expect to see in return: 

(in: 0 out: 0)
(in: 150 out: .05)
(in: 200 out: 0.5)
(in : 400.25 out: 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your code is equivalent to:

```
df['Total Hours'] = (df['Estimated_Size'] // 100) * 0.5
```

Except that I'm not clear what value you want when `Estimated_Size` is exactly `100`.

Comment: The reasoning behind that code is to increment the hours value for every 100 GB.  I am feeding in a list of integers that represent Estimated GB.

I am achieving this by checking if the number in the loop has no remainder when divided by 100 (which is what the percentage sign operator does in python).  If that is detected, the "hours" variable increments by 0.50.